# INSERT or UPDATE table from another table with composite primary key

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am looking for the correct syntax and way to do the following directly from SQL: insert or update (if data already exists inside) `TableMain` from data contained in `TableA` with both having same composite primary key.

Both tables are defined as :

```
CREATE TABLE TableA (
[TID0] [int] NOT NULL,
[TID1] [int] NOT NULL,
[language] [nvarchar](2) NOT NULL,
[TID2] [nvarchar](200) NOT NULL,
[text] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[updatedOn] [datetime] NOT NULL  DEFAULT (getdate())
PRIMARY KEY (
    [TID0],
    [TID1],
    [language],
    [TID2],
)
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

`TableA` will be periodically deleted and filled.

`TableMain` as the same definition but will contain many more rows of data and what I need is to insert never seen values from `TableA` into `TableMain`, and update already existing rows.

I used to do this kind of insert but I do not know how to handle update and composite primary keys :

```
INSERT INTO TableMain 
    SELECT * FROM TableA
```

EDIT : i am using **SQL Server 9.00.5000**

EDIT : another way inspired by MERGE and [mimick it](http://sqlserver-tips.blogspot.fr/2006/09/mimicking-merge-statement-in-sql.html)

```
DECLARE @updatedIDs TABLE(
    [TID0] [int],
    [TID1] [int],
    [language] [nvarchar](2),
    [TID2] [nvarchar](200),
                PRIMARY KEY ([TID0], [TID1], [language], [TID2])  -- as stated by Nikola Markovinović above, thanks
);

-- First update records 
update TableMain 
   set [text]      = source.[text], 
       [updatedOn] = source.[updatedOn] 
       OUTPUT
         inserted.[TID0]
         inserted.[TID1]
         inserted.[language]
         inserted.[TID2]
       INTO @updatedIDs
  from 
       TableMain AS main
       , TableA AS source 
  WHERE    
   TableMain.[TID0]         = source.[TID0] 
   and TableMain.[TID1]     = source.[TID1] 
   and TableMain.[language] = source.[language] 
   and TableMain.[TID2]     = source.[TID2] 

-- And then insert 

insert into TableMain
select *
  from TableA AS source 
 where not exists 
       ( 
      select 1
        from @updatedIDs AS i
       where i.[TID0]     = source.[TID0] 
         and i.[TID1]     = source.[TID1] 
         and i.[language] = source.[language] 
         and i.[TID2]     = source.[TID2] 
       )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a script you might use to upsert your data:

```
-- On error transaction is automatically rolled back
set xact_abort on

begin transaction
-- First update records
update TableMain
   set [text]      = source.[text],
       [updatedOn] = source.[updatedOn]
  from TableMain
 inner join TableA source
    on TableMain.[TID0]     = source.[TID0]
   and TableMain.[TID1]     = source.[TID1]
   and TableMain.[language] = source.[language]
   and TableMain.[TID2]     = source.[TID2]

-- And then insert

insert into TableMain ([TID0], [TID1], [language], [TID2], [text], [updatedOn])
select [TID0], [TID1], [language], [TID2], [text], [updatedOn]
  from TableA source
 where not exists
       (
          select *
            from TableMain
           where TableMain.[TID0]     = source.[TID0]
             and TableMain.[TID1]     = source.[TID1]
             and TableMain.[language] = source.[language]
             and TableMain.[TID2]     = source.[TID2]
       )

commit transaction
```

You might rewrite not exists() as `left join ... where TableMain.TID0 is null` if performance is not satisfactory.

Comment: thank you, BTW the others answers also helped me to find another working way with using a OUTPUT clause (that i do not know either before :))... Almost he same idea as your, with putting things inside a DECLARED table see : http://sqlserver-tips.blogspot.fr/2006/09/mimicking-merge-statement-in-sql.html
   i do not know what is the more effective approach...

Comment: ps : i also added this other way for future if it could help someone else

Comment: @user1340802 Output way is correct and probably faster because all not updated source records are new, and one does not have to search for matches in possibly a lot bigger source table, but implementation is lacking. Table variable `@updatedIDs` should have primary key(TID0, TID1, language, TID2) to be efficient, otherwise Sql Server assumes that it contains one row as statistics is not collected for table variable. Columns should be listed in order of selectivity - most selective first. This applies to TableA also.

Comment: thank you for your helps, added the primary key in the text !

Answer (score 5):

you should use a [merge](http://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb510625.aspx) statment

something like this:

```
merge TableMain  AS target
using TableA as source 
ON <join tables here>
WHEN MATCHED THEN <update>
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET <Insert>
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE <delete>
```

Comment: yes, but at the moment I asnwer he did not have the SQL2005 tag on the question :)

Answer (score 3):

you can use the [Merge](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) command from SQLServer 2008. It allows you to merge data from another data source into your main data source and define specific behavior when there is a key match (and you'll probably like to update your table) or there is not match and you'll like to insert the new record.

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/06/08/sql-server-merge-operations-insert-update-delete-in-single-execution/

you can visit this link to get few code samples.

Comment: very interesting, i do not know the MERGE statment BTW looks like my SQL Server 2005 do not accept it :/

Comment: the merge statement announced with SQLServer2008. if you're using 2005 version, I guess you'll have to use the old way of checking if exists and apply the relevant behavior. the merge is very powerful and promise atomicity and performance and many other goodies.