# SQL - Insert or Update with a result from another table

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, sql-update, insert-update

I have two tables `DailyVisits` and `TotalSum` My goal is to add `DailyVisits` to `TotalSum` with a stored procedure/query that I'll run at the end of the day.

```
DailyVisits
UserId,PageId,Visits
1,1,32
2,123,34
4,12,213
5,1,1

TotalSum
UserId,PageId,TotalVisits
1,1,300
1,41,2
3,12,213
5,1,653
```

and so on.

I tried two approaches but I can't get my head around a solution.

Below my queries to achieve this, if you have another suggestion/query simple enough to understand, I appreciate your help.

Approach1:

```
delimiter $$
CREATE PROCEDURE UPSERT_DAILYSUM()
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT Id, PageId FROM DailyVisits) THEN
        UPDATE TotalSum TotalVisits = TotalVisits + (SELECT Visits FROM DailyVisits);
    ELSE INSERT INTO TotalSum (UserId,PageId,TotalVisits) 
                         VALUES (SELECT Id,PageId,Visits);
    END IF
END $$
delimiter ;
```

Approach2:

```
INSERT INTO TotalSum (UserId,PageId,TotalVisits) VALUES(SELECT * FROM DailyVisits)
 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE (PageId,TotalVisits) 
               VALUES(SELECT PageId,Visits FROM DailyVisits)
```

This is what I'm struggling with: How will I get distinct values when key does not exist? Can I use `RIGHT JOIN` (or `LEFT JOIN`) and check for `NULL` values, and then add right (or left) table?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11883237/insert-or-update-table-from-another-table-with-composite-primary-key

Comment: Oh, yes it does! I have never thought of doing two update and insert separately. Thanks!

Comment: please give me an upvote if my answer helped you

Comment: Yes this could be happen when you construct a good trigger to do it. while inserting then update or insert to another table.

Comment: Same as Events too.. SP With events

Comment: If possible can you check the merge scripts for mysql

Comment: so hard for me coz i dont have your table. how could i construct a better one? this is not a simple problem to be solved.

Comment: im trying to study your problem..

Answer (score 0):

same as you need like this:

The problem is i dont know what you want to do in update and insert portion:

```
delimiter $$
CREATE PROCEDURE UPSERT_DAILYSUM()
BEGIN

Declare idvar int(50) DEFAULT 0;
Declare pageidvar int(50) DEFAULT 0;

SELECT Id, PageId INTO idvar,pageidvar  FROM DailyVisits;

if(LENGTH(idvar)>0 THEN
    UPDATE TotalSum TotalVisits = TotalVisits + (SELECT Visits FROM DailyVisits);
ELSE

 INSERT INTO TotalSum (UserId,PageId,TotalVisits)  VALUES (SELECT Id,PageId,Visits);

END $$
delimiter ;
```

Comment: What do you want to insert and what do you want to update. I mean what data value. it is just an example to have you a guide to do it. There's so many way to do it

Comment: I want to get a running sum for Visits column, if UserId & PageId matches. If they do not exist, then create new record and so on.

Comment: What do you mean running sum? when every time the record changed?